# Could not get unknown property 'lifecycle_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: java, android, dependencies, implementation

I want to create a ViewModel for my project,I also added the dependencies but it shows this error, how can I fix it?Also I am using the latest version of Android Studio and Java

Could not get unknown property 'lifecycle_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

````
 dependencies {
    //ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}```
````

Comment: Have you defined $lifecycle_version variable?

Comment: no I haven't,I was not aware I should\

Comment: yes. I posted the answer with a link. check it out.

Comment: found the answer,I took the code from Kotlin that's why it wan't working!thank you though

Comment: it is much appreciated if you could mark my answer if it is correct.

Comment: I just did it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your lifecycle_version.

```
dependencies {
        //Define your version here
        def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"

        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
        annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    //Other Dependencies

}
```

Check here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#groovy

Comment: There is another error->Could not find method kapt() for arguments [androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.5.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: I updated the answer. Use ```annotationProcessor``` instead of ```kapt```

Answer (score 1):

if you use kapt, don't forget to add kapt plugin to your gradle project